# Windows 11 Keyboard settings keep resetting

Tags: keyboard

So I've been having this issue on my Windows 11 keyboard where my keyboard repeat settings in the control panel keep automatically resetting to default, without any visible changes happening. So I'm forced to go back and change the slider and then change it back again, hit apply and that seems to fix the problem but it still keeps happening. Please help.

Comment: Whats the symptom. What behavior do you see that makes you go to the settings

Answer (score 2):

@Rohit Gupta, he already said the symptoms. I too am having the same problem. When you go into your keyboard settings and change the repeat slider (the option to decrease the wait time before a button triggers when holding the button down), the setting will return to the default setting upon restarting your computer even though when you return to it, it will show the slider just as where you left it. It is as if the setting will not stick in the windows registry. I am not sure what the registry entry is for it, but I am sure that is where the answer to the problem will be.

Edit: Just found this thread on microsoft. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-keyboard-repeat-rate-settings-change/44b2d3b4-ab8a-4cba-988e-e1f662881be2. Try editing your registry with the following information.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Control Panel \ Accessibility \ Keyboard Response]
"AutoRepeatDelay" = "200"
"AutoRepeatRate" = "10"
"DelayBeforeAcceptance" = "0"
"Flags" = "27"
"BounceTime" = "0"
```

(information is copied from the above link. Use at own discretion.)

Comment: Sorry,  settings getting lost is not the symptom. Z symptom would be what happens to the keyboard entry.  But upvoted it